# Export HTML data to a pdf/doc

Tags: html, angular, export

I'm working with angular 6 and have a form that a user fills in some information.  I'm looking for any recommendations on how to be able to export the form titles, labels and the user data to either a PDF or a word doc.  I've looked online and came across jsPDF and similar libraries, however they all appear to take a screenshot of the webpage which isn't what i'm looking for.  I'm looking for a way to be able to export the required (not all) html elements needed and be able to format the text size etc.

Comment: Maybe pdfmake.org is what you are searching for?

Answer (score 0):

They will all basically print the html container in which your form resides. what you need is a reporting tool. For example if you're using java on server side, you can use Jasper Reports. I personally use iReport tool for designing. With iReport you can design your form as you like by drag and drop functionality. Then u can pass a bean or list to it using java and jasper classes will fill that report and you can download it as pdf, doc, csv,html etc.

https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/getting-started-jasperreports-library

itext is an another example. Let me know if you are using java then i can help you in detail.

If you're using some other technology , then look for reporting tool similar to jasper reports